# Generate and render html content near cursor with JS function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a requirement to display tool tip on the legend of D3 charts. I read the documentation and I cannot find if legend supports tool tip. However, I was able to find mouse-over event.

I want to render a table near the cursor with a java script function.

I have the following method:

```
/**
 * Creates legend
 * barData - data from given (i.e. mouse is currently hover it)
 */
function createLegendTooltip(data) {
    var tooltip =
        '<table><tr>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<div style="width:10px;height:10px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:' + data.color + '"></div>' +
        '</td><td>' +
        data.instance +
        '</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td>' +
         data.saver + ', karan' + data.saveTime +
        '</td></tr></table>';
        return tooltip;
}
```

The `tooltip` have the correct data that I intend to display but I am not able to figure out how to render this data near the cursor.

Comment: You should be looking to position the tooltip based on `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY`. [Here's](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) an example. If you're looking for a working solution, please provide a working/runnable code snippet with the chart (or at least the legends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body.In your mouseover event you can get the mouse position with pageX and pageY. Then you know where the mouse is on the screen. With this information you can create a div and position it where the mouse is. 
You can use your html string that is returned from createLegendTooltip and apply it to the div with .innerHTML

Very generic example below. Theres more you have to do. For example set the z-index and also creates a function that updates the position of the coolDiv if you want it to move when the mouse moves.

```
var coolDiv = document.createElement('div');
coolDiv.innerHTML = createLegendTooltip(data);
coolDiv.style.left = yourValueYouGetFrom_pageX;
coolDiv.style.top = yourValueYouGetFrom_pageY;
document.body.appendChild(coolDiv);
```

Comment: Your'e right. If you want to append it to the body then it should be document.body =) I was in a hurry when i wrote the answer.